Is main actor's init isolated or not in Swift (Xcode Beta 5)
The following code worked fine in Xcode 16 Beta 4, but fails to compile in beta 5:

@MainActor
class TimerSchudler {
  init() {
  }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
  let scheduler = TimerSchudler()
  
  override init() {
    super.init()
  }
  
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}

I got this error:

Property 'self.scheduler' not initialized at super.init call

Then I move the scheduler initialization inside the init:
class GameScene: SKScene {
  let scheduler: TimerSchudler
  
  override init() {
    scheduler = TimerSchudler()
    super.init()
  }
  
}

This becomes a warning:

Call to main actor-isolated initializer 'init()' in a synchronous nonisolated context; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode

Which means TimerScheduler's init function is now on main actor.
If I change it to use an actor that's not main actor:

actor TimerSchudler {
  init() {
  }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
  let scheduler: TimerSchudler
  
  override init() {
    scheduler = TimerSchudler()
    super.init()
  }
  
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}

This compiles just fine. This means non-main actor's init is still nonisolated.
My understanding is that all actor's init should be nonisolated. However, it looks like in Beta 5, Apple made MainActor's init to be main actor isolated. This is problematic, because SKScene's init is not on main actor. So if I mark the init as main actor like this:
class GameScene: SKScene {
  let scheduler: TimerSchudler

  @MainActor
  override init() {
    scheduler = TimerSchudler()
    super.init()
  }
}

I will get a warning:

Main actor-isolated initializer 'init()' has different actor isolation from nonisolated overridden declaration; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode

So how I can work around this?

That's weird. This init you are trying to override is from SKNode, which is main actor isolated on all platforms (except watchOS).

@Sweeper It turns out Beta 6 fixed this. However, SCNScene still fails since it inherits directly from NSObject (odd difference between SpriteKit and SceneKit). You can verify by replacing SKScene to SCNScene.

For SCNScene, the warnings and errors are completely justified. Don’t you agree?

Ya i agree it's justified, though I'm thinking about a solution to SCNScene, since my usage in SCNScene and SKScene are similar. I am not sure why Apple chose different design for the 2 very similar concepts


all actor's init should be nonisolated

Correct.

Apple made MainActor's init to be main actor isolated

You did not init "MainActor." You call init on a class (not an actor) that is isolated to MainActor. And yes, that init is on MainActor since it inherits the @MainActor attribute. (Again, attribute. It's not an actor. It's a class isolated to MainActor.)

So how I can work around this?

You provided the way and said "this compiles just fine."
You can also mark TimeSchudler.init nonisolated if you want that:
@MainActor
class TimerSchudler {
    nonisolated init() {
    }
}


Hmmm, the same logic applies to GameScene right? Why isn't GameScene's init main isolated?

Because SKScene.init (its superclass) isn't main isolated. That what the final warning is telling you. "has different actor isolation from nonisolated overridden declaration." You can't change isolations in subclasses.

But the superclass goes all the way up to UIResponder, which is marked as @MainActor.

FWIW, I think Rob Napier’s answer (+1) should be accepted.

@OMGPOP – Technically, UIResponder is an ObjC type marked NS_SWIFT_UI_ACTOR (whose overridden init defaults to nonisolated), unlike Swift @MainActor type, whose override of  init does default to isolated. Now, if this was your own Objective-C type, you could mark your base ObjC type’s init with NS_SWIFT_UI_ACTOR, too, but Apple has apparently not done that for UIResponder. (I don't know if this was an oversight, or a conscious decision.)

This is a bit tricky because my TimerScheduler's init cannot be nonisolated, because it has some fields that needs to be isolated to main :( Why is NS_SWIFT_UI_ACTOR behaving differently from @MainActor? What's the benefit of doing this?

NS_SWIFT_UI_ACTOR is just an annotation that says that things should be run on MainActor (or is documentation that this is where the system will call them). It does not inject additional code like @MainActor does in some cases. This is a bit similar to things like ObjC lightweight generics which tell the system how to bridge ObjC datatypes but do not actually enforce things in ObjC. A lot of ObjC/Swift annotations are like this. They just help make the imported signatures nicer. They often do not actually do anything.

It looks like Beta 6 fixed this. No error anymore and the init becomes main isolated as expected. However, my SceneKit game still fails (You can replace SKScene to SCNScene and notice the same error)

From the class hierarchy, SCNScene simply inherits from NSObject, and not UIResponder.
